# Golang (cgo) - Support for nested structs with cgo?

Tags: c, struct, go, cgo

I was trying to use cgo to write a little wrapper for the x264 library and came across a problem with nested structs. The library uses a lot of complicated structs where some of the fields are anonymous structs themselves.

When trying to use cgo to access these structs, I run in to compilation errors because go claims that the nested structs do not exist.

I've managed to boil down the problem into a .h file and a .go file pasted below. Hopefully that is clear enough to show the problem.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround to this problem?

Thanks.

### struct.h

```
typedef struct param_struct_t {
  int a;
  int b;
  struct {
    int c;
    int d;
  } anon;
  int e;
  struct {
    int f;
    int g;
  } anon2;
} param_struct_t;
```

### main.go

```
package main
/*
#include "struct.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  var param C.param_struct_t
  fmt.Println(param.a) // Works and should work
  fmt.Println(param.b) // Works and should work
  fmt.Println(param.c) // Works fine but shouldn't work
  fmt.Println(param.d) // Works fine but shouldn't work
  // fmt.Println(param.e) // Produces type error: ./main.go:17: param.e undefined (type C.param_struct_t has no field or method e)
  // fmt.Println(param.anon) // Produces type error: ./main.go:18: param.anon undefined (type C.param_struct_t has no field or method anon)

  // The following shows that the first parameters and the parameters from the
  // first anonymous struct gets read properly, but the subsequent things are
  // read as seemingly raw bytes.
  fmt.Printf("%#v", param) // Prints out: main._Ctype_param_struct_t{a:0, b:0, c:0, d:0, _:[12]uint8{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Go are you using?  Using Go 1.1.2, cgo seems to produce the expected output.

I ran `go tool cgo main.go`, and the generated `_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go` file contained the following definitions:

```
type _Ctype_param_struct_t _Ctype_struct_param_struct_t

type _Ctype_struct___0 struct {
//line :1
        c       _Ctype_int
//line :1
        d       _Ctype_int
//line :1
}

type _Ctype_struct___1 struct {
//line :1
        f       _Ctype_int
//line :1
        g       _Ctype_int
//line :1
}

type _Ctype_struct_param_struct_t struct {
//line :1
        a       _Ctype_int
//line :1
        b       _Ctype_int
//line :1
        anon    _Ctype_struct___0
//line :1
        e       _Ctype_int
//line :1
        anon2   _Ctype_struct___1
//line :1
}
```

When I modified your program to correctly refr to `c` and `d` nested in the `anon` field and uncommented the other statements, the program compiled and ran with the final statement printing the struct as.

```
main._Ctype_param_struct_t{a:0, b:0, anon:main._Ctype_struct___0{c:0, d:0}, e:0, anon2:main._Ctype_struct___1{f:0, g:0}}
```

If you are using an older version of Go, perhaps try upgrading.  You could also try running `cgo` manually like I did to see what it is generating if you still run into problems.

Comment: I am running go 1.2rc2, which might explain the problem. When outputting the types with `go tool cgo main.go` i get a struct like this: type _Ctype_struct_param_struct_t struct {
//line :1
 a _Ctype_int
//line :1
 b _Ctype_int
//line :1
 c _Ctype_int
//line :1
 d _Ctype_int
//line :1
 _ [12]byte
//line :1
}

Comment: In that case, it sounds like a bug.  Probably best to report it in the bug tracker or mailing list.

Comment: It was indeed fixed by downgrading to go1.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with cgo. But you cannot directly use the C type in your go code as cgo as re-generated its own types. Maybe it's _C_param_struct_t.

Please refer to this official doc: http://golang.org/misc/cgo/gmp/gmp.go